# how to rectify the errors of div behaving like a file browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-browser

my problem:i have a code that im using to make a div behave like a file browser but it keeps on giving a error `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleFileSelect is not defined` when inspected in google chromes console how to rectify it

my code:

```
<input class="image_select" id="image_select" type="file" name="image" style="display:none">

<script>
    document.getElementById('image_select').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>

<div class="faker_select_button-singular" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('image_select').click();">
        Select My Image
</div>
```

NOTE:not that the error is any problem i just dont like having errors in the website

Comment: Create the callback function and name it `handleFileSelect`

Comment: What @PatrickEvans said, do something like `function handleFileSelect() {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you upfront exactly what the error is. You did not define the `handleFileSelect` callback function.

Define the function for God's sake.

That's how you define a function:

```
function handleFileSelect()
{
    //code
}
```

Just put this snippet before you add the listener and it'll throw no error.